# How can I show the result of an AJAX request in a dialog box?

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I have some data on the server that i want to print in the dialog box, what i am trying to is the following.

```
$(function() {
    $("#checkreservatoion").click(function() {
        // getting selected date
        var selected_date = $("#sd").val(); 

        // getting route details    
        var selected_route = $("#route option:selected").val(); 

        // getting the details of seats
        var selected_sites = $("#qty option:selected").text();
        $.post("abc.php", {
            date: selected_date,
            route: selected_route,
            seats: selected_sites 
        }, function(ajaxresult) {
            //getting ajax result and printing as html 
            $("#postrequest").html(ajaxresult);
        });
    });
});
```

but this code is not working, where `#postrequest` is the div for model that is a jQuery plugin.

Comment: please reorganize your code.

Comment: You should also specify what the exact problem is.

Comment: Downvotes are a little harsh here. I've seen a lot worse questions than this one.

Comment: user1468327, you could have saved yourself many, many down votes if you had just taken the time to format your code before posting.

Comment: okay i got it. i'll keep it in mind next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alert(ajaxresult)
```

instead of

```
$("#postrequest").html(ajaxresult);
```

It will show a basic dialogue box but the use is generally discouraged

or for a much more stylish one:
html:

```
<div class="dialogue">
    <div class="header">
        This is an alert!
    </div>
    <div class="body">

   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.dialogue{
    position:none;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-top:-250px;
}
.dialogue > .header{
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
}
.dialogue > .body{
    width:100%;
    height:480px;
}
```

js

```
$(function() {
    $("#checkreservatoion").click(function() {
        // getting selected date
        var selected_date = $("#sd").val(); 

        // getting route details    
        var selected_route = $("#route option:selected").val(); 

        // getting the details of seats
        var selected_sites = $("#qty option:selected").text();
        $.post("abc.php", {
            date: selected_date,
            route: selected_route,
            seats: selected_sites 
        }, function(ajaxresult) {
            //getting ajax result and printing as html 
            $(".dialogue > .body").html(ajaxresult);
            $(".dialogue").css("position","fixed");
        });
    });
});
```

I have not tested this code but it should work

Comment: sorry buddy, i want fancy dialog like facebox please help???

Comment: @user1468327. Stack Overflow is not a place to get people to do your job or homework for you. It is a place to ask a specific question and hopefully receive an answer for that specific question. robinp7720 in this case has gone above and beyond what is required to answer your question.